Is it possible to pre-define client side ftps ports in passive mode?
I am trying to connect to an ftp server available on the internet with credentials given to me. I am behind a corporation firewall, any changes in policy take forever to implement so I am trying to understand what I need before I request. It is up to me to request changes to policy that is fairly restrictive by default. I know it is possible to access server's contents outside my firewall. In my case, currently the connection timeouts the moment it comes to using the data channel(is my diagnosis correct?):
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (172,16,10,10,78,46)
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Command: MLSD
Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for MLSD.
Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity

From what I understand passive ftp makes the server say connect to me here: server_ip:random_port. This is fine however, I've read that the client port will be random. I have every reason to think this random port on my side is getting blocked by my own firewall.
In general the internet speaks a lot about how to configure ports on the server side, how you cannot influence server's ports as a client in passive mode, or what the order of initiating contact(active vs passive) is etc. but I could not find information on setting my own client ports.
So the question is: is there a way to predefine, using ftps passive mode, one particular port or a range of ports that my machine will connect from, so that I can configure the firewall in advance? If not, are there any alternative solutions? Filezilla, linux terminal, python are fine.


however, I've read that the client port will be random. I have every reason to think this random port on my side is getting blocked by my own firewall.

Then your own firewall is very much misconfigured.
It's not a behavior specific to FTP passive mode – nearly every TCP-based protocol uses a random port number on the client side. I can remember only one or two examples that do not. So generally host-side firewalls don't really look at the client port number, and if this were the problem, then it would be causing issues with various other software as well.
It's a bit more likely that some firewall is blocking connections based on the server-side port number.
(Sometimes firewalls try to snoop on the PORT/PASV commands and automatically allow the necessary data connections, and TLS of course completely prevents that from happening...)
A TCP client can choose the local port number manually, in which case the answer depends on which FTP client you're using – it's possible that some have such an option, or that some even re-use the same "active FTP" port range for this (given that it's actually the same bind operation in both cases). I cannot test Filezilla at the moment, but I'm sure it has an option for the active-mode ports and it's worth trying to see if it works for passive mode as well.
But if this ends up helping, then you're using some weird firewall rules.
Some operating systems also allow setting a custom "ephemeral port" range system-wide, which you could use in a pinch (keeping in mind that it affects all connections, so if you set it to a small range you can run out of port numbers). For Windows it's under netsh, for Linux there is a sysctl parameter.
Linux also allows you to SNAT connections via iptables; usually it's used to change the source address but it can just as well change the TCP port number.
